# Building a house that is warm in winter and cool in summer

Tags: thermodynamics, thermal-radiation, thermal-conductivity, convection

The Northern house architecture is strikingly different from that used in the South (I am not taking extreme cases, thinking more of Northern or Germany versus Mediterranean:

- *Thick layers of thermal isolation, airtight walls, and large windows oriented to the South* assure that no heat is being lost. The current European regulations (like [Euro 2020](https://www.en-standard.eu/bs-en-iso-9229-2020-thermal-insulation-vocabulary/) aim at houses being thermally inert, i.e., spending zero energy to remain warm in winter.)
- The opposite: *no isolation, free airflow, and small windows under the ceiling* is typical Mediterranean architecture, with obvious goal of preventing the house from heating in Summer.

The southern houses may be somewhat uncomfortable in winter, if the temperature falls in teens, and the northern houses incur some suffering during the hot Summer days, which become more and more numerous with every year. My question is mainly regarding the latter: *Are there (and what are) the tricks/solutions for building a house that is warm in winter and cool in Summer?*

Is compromising on Winter warmth or Summer chill the only option (which in some cases seems to be almost ruled out by the regulations for the new constructions)?

Comment: I would have thought that [thermal mass](https://www.smarterhomes.org.nz/smart-guides/design/thermal-mass-for-heating-and-cooling/)  is something which needs to be considered?

Comment: @Farcher Thanks, this is interesting. If you feel like expanding it into an answer, feel free to do so.

Comment: I do not know where you get the mediterranean architecture.  Do you have a link for your descriptions?

Comment: @annav This is more personal observations - I had [something like this](http://america.aljazeera.com/articles/2013/11/25/israel-approves-newsettlementsinwestbank.html) in mind. I can't speak for the whole Mediterranean, but this seems typical for the Levant, Spain and Portugal - the windows are really tiny, somewhere under the ceiling, and very poorly isolated, so it can easily make 15C inside in winter, if the outside temperature is as low. I am not talking about palaces or high architecture, but the family houses. (Admittedly, these are impressions of somebody from North.)

Answer (score 2):

This is far more of an engineering than physics problem, but here are some suggestions.

A well-insulated building will shield the interior from external high temperature just as much as from low temperature.  How hot it gets inside depends on the amount of energy generated (and human bodies generate a LOT) and the heat flow rate thru the walls.  The Euro rules, so far as I recall, also require significant active air transfer to avoid poisoning the inhabitants.

The open-flow Mediterranean style is simply the best achievable at the time in history they were developed, and of course for much of the time the outdoor temperature is the desired temperature so everyone's happy.  Free-flow is not a way to keep the interior cooler than the exterior. To induce cooling, you need things like a double-roof, preferable with a wider gap at the prevailing downwind direction. This produces expansion cooling (see Statistical Mechanics).

In sum: you can't stay warmer than the outside without heat sources. You can't stay cooler than the outside without a heat dump.  The rest is a cost & engineering tradeoff.

Comment: Thanks, this is useful.